# SQLite Group By results order behaviour change 3.28.0 onwards

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have noticed an issue with the order of results using "GROUP BY" with later versions of SQLite that am struggling to solve. I first noticed it when Android 11 came out as it uses SQLite 3.28.0. I have now pinned it down to a behaviour change in SQLite itself.
The issue is the the order of results is changed depending on the version. I'm not sure if it's a bug or intended behaviour or an error on my part (albeit an error that has been working fine for 8 years with older SQLite versions).

Example table:

```
id|year|command |code
1 |2005|TV      |A
2 |2005|TV-CD   |B
3 |2005|CD      |B
4 |2010|TV      |B
5 |2015|TV      |C
```

If I run the following command

```
SELECT * FROM myTable  GROUP BY command ORDER BY _id
```

With in SQLite 3.22 (Android 10) or 3.23.1 I get:

```
2|2005|TV-CD|B
3|2005|CD   |B
5|2015|TV   |C
```

Which is what I want...

If I run the same command in SQLite 3.28 (Android 11) or higher I get

```
1|2005|TV   |A
2|2005|TV-CD|B
3|2005|CD   |B
```

Here's a quick sample of the table if you want to try it for yourself

```
CREATE TABLE 'myTable' ('_id' integer PRIMARY KEY  ,'year' NUMERIC ,'command' TEXT, 'code' TEXT);
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ("1","2005","TV","A");
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ("2","2005","TV-CD","B");
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ("3","2005","CD","B");
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ("4","2010","TV","B");
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ("5","2015","TV","C");
SELECT * FROM myTable  GROUP BY command ORDER BY _id
```

https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-sql-online/ was useful for testing as it allows you to change the SQLite version on the fly.

Comment: You are grouping by command so other values should not be relevant unless it's aggregation(like count, average, sum, etc. but you didn't use any)

Comment: You should not use code like: SELECT * FROM myTable  GROUP BY command. SQLite allows it (although other databases don't). But it does not make sense. The results of such queries are unpredictable. So there is no correct or wrong result. You have to rethink about the result that you want.

Comment: You may use `max` aggregation to get last id.. But for other values you have to use subquery /cte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in my comment, the result of a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable  GROUP BY command
```

is unpredictable, because `GROUP BY` should be used only for aggregation, something like:

```
SELECT command, MAX(year) AS max_year 
FROM myTable  
GROUP BY command
```

which will return the max `year` for each `command`.

So if the behavior of `GROUP BY` with `SELECT * ...` has changed in newer versionsshould not be a problem if you did not use such queries.

From what I read in your question, you are expecting in the results for each `command` the row with the max `id`.

In standard sql and without window functions, which are still not supported in most versions of android SQLite, you could aggregate first and then join to the table.

But, SQLite has a [documented feature](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#simple_select_processing) to use so that you can use *bare* columns.
 This is valid:

```
SELECT MAX(_id) AS _id, year, command, code
FROM myTable  
GROUP BY command
ORDER BY _id
```

You will get the row with the max `_id` for each `command`.

Comment: this bare columns feature is a good find! But it also looks like a good opportunity for errors (as there is ambiguity if there are more than one min/max, for example)

Comment: @njzk2 No, this is well documented. This works only if there is only MIN or only MAX. In any other case the result is unpredictable.

Comment: that's what I'm saying. It's a very interesting feature, but can easily lead to errors or misunderstanding, if someone in the future modify that query without understanding that particular feature.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution and can confirm it works in both versions of SQLite

```
SELECT _id,MAX (year),command,code FROM myTable  GROUP BY command  ORDER BY _id
```